# How to use external css for a background image with gedit

Tags: css, background-image

I am taking a couple of classes about HTML and CSS but I am really having a difficult time understanding how to make a background image with external css. I am successful at external css in other ways, just not a background image.

This is my code for the HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>

    <title>Forms</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS/forms.css">
   </head>
   <body>
   <div id="Pictures"</div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

And this is my code for the CSS:

```
#Pictures {
    background-image:url(../home/brian/Desktop/Becky.JPG);
}
```

I can get it to work using the `<style>` tag but not external CSS.

Comment: Just sounds like your image path is incorrect `../home/brian/Desktop/Becky.JPG`. Update your question with your folder structure.

Comment: @J08691- thank you for your comment. I'm betting your right, because I'm not sure what you mean. I thought /home/brian/Desktop/Becky.JPG was the folder structure. I am using Ubuntu if that helps. This may provide a clue as well. I am finding the folder structure this way:I find the image, then right click and scoll down to properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File structure is key. Where is your *.html* file located in relation to your *.jpg* file?

I suggest that you use another folder (call it 'assets' or 'images', something like that) to put your images into, instead of putting them on your Desktop.
So, in your case your file structure would look like this:

*index.html

css/forms.css

assets/Becky.jpg*

The path in your external css file would then be:

```
#Pictures {
  background-image: url(../assets/Becky.jpg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#pictures {
  background: url("http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/img_flwr.gif");
  background-size: 80px 60px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <title>Forms</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/home/red/Desktop/Web Projects/Test/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="pictures"></div>
</body>

</html>
```